# deploy my next.js project on vercel, Cannot find module 'react-icons/Fa' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

I am deploying my nextjs typescript project on vercel. However, I got an error. May I ask how to fix this bug?? Should I run "npm run build" and push to github again? Thank you so much[image]

How to fix this bug on vercel "Cannot find module 'react-icons/Fa' or its corresponding type declarations."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're importing your icon incorrectly.

Instead of

`import { FaPlay } from "react-icons/Fa";`

try

`import { FaPlay } from "react-icons/fa";`

Notice the lowercase `fa` on the second one. I found this by looking at the react-icons documentation here: https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/icons?name=fa

Hope this helps!

Comment: If this is the issue I'll be pretty surprised - but I guess it's possible if you're on Linux.

Comment: Try to reach out with OP with a comment before posting an answer, this seems an environmental issue so future readers don't assume this is always the solution