# Vercel can't deploy due to react icons module is not found but it is actually installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, react-icons

I am trying to deploy a project to Vercel but it marks down an error on the building phase, saying react icons can't be found even if it is installed to `package.json` and imported correctly to the component that uses that module.

Here is the public repository where is all my code since it planned to be public: https://github.com/Benevos/react-nextjs-tailwind-juice-slider

This is the faulty component:

```
'use client';

import React from 'react';
import Link from "next/link";

import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";

import { FaCircleUser } from "react-icons/fa6"; \\ <---- Here is where the error shows
import { FaShoppingBag } from "react-icons/fa";

import { Londrina_Solid } from 'next/font/google';

const londrinaSolid = Londrina_Solid({weight: '400' , subsets: ['latin']});

function Header({ backgroundColor, textColor }) {
  return (
    <header id="header" style={{backgroundColor: backgroundColor, color: textColor}}
              className={`flex justify-start items-center 
                          py-4 font-semibold
                          relative transition duration-[1600ms] z-0`}>

        <Link href={"/#"} className={`text-3xl flex-initial ml-10 
                                        max-md:ml-5 ${londrinaSolid.className}`}>
            Trademark
        </Link>

        <Navbar/>

        <div className="flex text-xl gap-4 
                        flex-initial ml-auto
                        mr-10 max-md:mr-5">

            <Link href={"/#"}>
            <FaCircleUser/>
            </Link>

            <Link href={"/#"}>
            <FaShoppingBag/>
            </Link>
        </div>  

    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

This is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "juice-slider-vercel-fix",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

Vercel logs:

[image]

I used the suggested command by react icons documentation to install the module (`npm install react-icons --save`).

Already tried to start a fresh project installing react icons at beggining and importing all the source code but still not working.

I also checked [deploy my next.js project on vercel, Cannot find module 'react-icons/Fa' or its corresponding type declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778643/deploy-my-next-js-project-on-vercel-cannot-find-module-react-icons-fa-or-its) but seems not to be the problem.

Someone knows what could be the problem, please?

Comment: are you able to display  `react-icons/fa6` on ui

Comment: Yes, development server runs perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code builds

[image]

and starts with `npm run start`

[image]

Maybe you need to update `node` version. my system has:

```
node --version
v18.17.1
```

I also deployed on vercel successfully:

[image]

here is the production link:

https://testing-vercel-bay.vercel.app/

check your vercel settings for node version

[image]

Comment: As can be seen in `package.json` in this post, there is no `react-icons` key in the object that contains `devDependencies`. By te way, I also looked for installations globally, but `npm -g ls` showed no sign of `react-icons` there.

Comment: I just realized that. do u have a git repo?

Comment: It's written on the post: https://github.com/Benevos/react-nextjs-tailwind-juice-slider
Also, Nettlify did the deployment with no problems.

Comment: I know how to start production server, I have already build my project. But this is not about that. The problem is on Vercel and its hosting. Im glad you are trying to help, but did you even read the post?

Comment: since I started, I will deploy too

Comment: Thanks, I do not know what just happened, Vercel deployed without me doing anything at all few seconds ago. I'll mark your answer as solution since seems you did something that dealt with the problem

Comment: maybe vercel had issue at that moment